# plotting both continuous/broken and discrete data in R; time on the x-axis and bins on the y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two sets of measurements for different sites: one that was collected at discrete times and one where different gauges were left at sites for continuous periods of time. I want to plot when each site was measured, with both the continuous and discrete measurement periods on the same plot. Here is a simplified example of the data I have and what I would want:

Here is a data.frame of each well and different time periods when a gauge was making measurements. Start_date is when the gauge was put at the site, and end_date is when the guage was removed.

site

start_date

end_date

west-1  01/02/18    01/04/18
west-1  01/20/18    02/20/18
west-1  03/15/18    04/05/18
west-2  01/16/18    03/01/18
west-2  03/15/18    04/05/18
east    01/03/18    01/05/18
east    01/09/18    01/11/18
east    02/20/18    03/15/18
east    03/27/18    03/29/18

Here is a data.frame of the discrete measurement dates of each site, where someone went out on date and made a manual measurement:

site

date

west-1  01/02/18
west-1  01/18/18
west-1  03/05/18
west-1  04/01/18
west-2  01/02/18
west-2  03/15/18
west-2  04/01/18
east    01/02/18
east    01/18/18
east    02/15/18
east    03/15/18
11 rows

I want to plot these measurement periods so time is on the x-axis, and the y-axis is comprised of bins that are each site (west-1, west-2, and east). Horizontal lines of one color would mark continuous gauge measurements (for example, there would be a horizontal line with a left endpoint at 01/02/18 and right endpoint at 01/04/18, and on the same level vertically as the west-1 bin). Points would represent discrete measurements. Like this:
[a drawing of the plot I'm hoping for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0ynv.jpg)

The closest thing I can get is with ggplot; a histogram with flipped axes. But this isn't right because this data isn't for a histogram, and I couldn't make multiple breaks.